# Data is not displayed in the template

Tags: meteor, parse-platform

I am using [Parse](http://parse.com) inside a [Meteor](http://meteor.com) application.  Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1 style="color: red;">Meteor & Parse DB Demo</h1>
        </header>
        {{>header}}
    </div>
</body>

<template name="header">
{{#each alphabets}}
    <div class="alphabets">{{this}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

JS:

```
Parse.initialize("appid", "jsid");
var list_item=Parse.Object.extend("className");
var query=new Parse.Query(list_item);
var list=[];

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  query.find({
    success:function(o){
      for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
        var object = o[i];
        list.push(object.get('name'));
        console.log(list);
      }
      return list;
    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }

  });
  Template.header.alphabets = function() {
    return list;
  };
}
</template>
```

The data is coming from the database, but the problem is that the template is loaded before the data arrives:

`template.headed.alphabet` is called before `query.find` is is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code which worked for me i am posting this so other can refer it.

```
HTML:

<body>
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <h1 style="color: red;">Meteor & Parse DB Demo</h1>
    </header>
    {{>header}}
</div>
</body>

<template name="header">
{{#each alphabets}}
    <div class="alphabets">{{this.name}}</div>
{{/each}}

JS:

Parse.initialize("appid", "jsid");
var list_item=Parse.Object.extend("className");
var query=new Parse.Query(list_item);
var list=[];

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  query.find({
    success:function(o){
      for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
        var object = o[i];
        list.push({name:object.get('name')});
        console.log(list);
      }
      return list;
    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }

  });
  Template.header.alphabets = function() {
    return list;
  };
}
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your list a client side collection, it will then be reactive and update

```
list = new Mongo.Collection(null);
```

then do `list.insert(object.get('name'))`

```
Parse.initialize("appid", "jsid");
var list_item=Parse.Object.extend("className");
var query=new Parse.Query(list_item);

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  list = new Mongo.Collection(null);
  query.find({
    success:function(o){
      for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
        var object = o[i];
        list.insert(object.get('name'));

      }

    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }

  });
  Template.header.helpers({
     alphabets : function() {
      return list.find({});
     }
  });
}
</template>
```

Comment: doesn't matter, still use a client side collection, it doesn't talk to mongo, its a thing called minimongo,  in this case, disconnected from mongo.  It provides reactive collections, which is what you want. Meaning it will re-render when the list gets updated

Comment: nope, no class name, if you give it a name, then it will think it is connected to mongo, but with null, its like an array but, reactive, completely disconnected from mongo

Comment: it means object.get('name')   is an object....  if it has properties you want to display....

Comment: you need to do  {{propertyName}}  where propertyname is some property on that object

Comment: I'm not sure what it is...   you can do a console.log(object.get('name'))  just after the list insert and look at what it is ( paste it here if you like)